# Tub spout set screw leaking

Tags: bathtub, spout

I had to take my tub spout off the wall to replace the diverter, and when I caulked it back on, I didn't caulk over the set screw area (I read specifically not to). However, quite a bit of water is dripping out of that area now, way more than previously. I'm worried it will damage my wall/tub over time. Is this something that can be fixed? Should I caulk over the hole? Is there another solution?

Comment: Usually a set screw should not be in the path of the water(in pipes).  There is probably a leak that happens to use the set screw hole to come out.  Will need to undo and find the leak.

Comment: I'll undo it. Where am I looking for possible leaks?

Comment: It also only leaks in shower mode, not bath mode. So maybe something with the diverter.

Comment: If you post a picture someone might be able to help